# php file - get html content into array by tag

Tags: php, arrays, file, file-get-contents

---

**UPDATE: This code works so far. Still tweeking.**

```
$trimmed = file('http://www.edvizenor.com/mercy/love/dm8.php');

foreach ($trimmed as $line_num => $line) 
{


if(preg_match("/<td class=\"num\">/",  $trimmed[$line_num], $matches))

  {   
 $num++;
  }


  $Content[$num] .= $trimmed[$line_num];




}

// Example array! 
echo $Content[6];
```

////

### END UPDATE

---

I am trying to get table contents into an array using php. I would like to get all the paragraphs after each number into an array.

Here is the url: http://edvizenor.com/mercy/love/dm8.php

I need to have the text content of each paragraph number into an array as well as the paragraph number too. Once I have that then I want to save them in a folder into a txt file named by there paragraph number.

For example after I get the contents into the correct array then if I want to call paragraph #832 then I would do something like this:

```
$par = file_get_contents("353.txt"); 
// Need code to get only number
echo $num;
echo "<br>";
echo $par;

// should echo out:
353 
When Mother left for the chapel and I stayed to set the room in order,
I heard these words: Tell all the sisters that I demand that they live
in the spirit of faith towards the superiors at this present time. I 
begged my confessor to release me from this duty.
```

I thought about putting the whole content into a string and "exploding";

```
$Content = file_get_contents("http://edvizenor.com/mercy/love/dm8.php");
$ContentArray = explode("<td class=\"num\">", $Content);
```

but this is getting complicated. So I stopped it.

Any ideas on the best way to do this. I have a total of 1868 paragraphs and content. So copy and paste would be a lot of work. Thankfully, all the html is written the same so I should be able to find a pattern and do what I want accordingly. But I can't figure it out so I turn to the wise ones on StackOverflow :)

Comment: Personally, I like to tackle this sort of thing with http://php.net/domxpath

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to grab the content of the url into a variable and then use domxpath to query it and loop it into array.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom -> loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nums = $xpath->query("//td[@class='num']");
$paragraphs = $xpath->query("//td[@class='num']/following::td[1]");

for($j = 0; $j < $nums->length; $j++){
    $num = $nums->item($j)->nodeValue;
    $para = $paragraphs->item($j)->nodeValue;

    $para_array[$num] = $para;
}
```

This is the example result.
http://randtest.site11.com/